# PHPUnit Works locally but some tests fail on TravisCI - Status code [500]

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, travis-ci

I'm currently running some tests and everything works perfectly locally. As soon as I run them on Travis I get an error but I can't explain myself why.

Fun Fact: I use for example the same code (Just with different routes) in other tests and it works locally and on Travis.

```
Tests: 372, Assertions: 906, Failures: 1.
```

I tried to get a workaround with calling the page by a JSON or a GET Request instead of using the Visit-Method. Without any success.

**Travis Error**

```
1) Tests\Feature\Administrators\Users\UsersControllerTest::administrators_can_visit_administrators_users_index
A request to [http://localhost:8000/backend/administrators/users] failed. Received status code [500].
/home/travis/build/StanBarrows/ch.example/vendor/laravel/browser-kit-testing/src/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:220
/home/travis/build/StanBarrows/ch.example/vendor/laravel/browser-kit-testing/src/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:92
/home/travis/build/StanBarrows/ch.example/vendor/laravel/browser-kit-testing/src/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:73
/home/travis/build/StanBarrows/ch.example/tests/Feature/Administrators/Users/UsersControllerTest.php:44
```

**Test 1 - administrators_can_visit_administrators_users_index**

```
$route = 'backend.administrators.users.index';
$this->logInAs(null, 'administrator');
$this->visitRoute($route);
$this->assertResponseOk();
$this->seeRouteIs($route);
```

**Tried workarounds**

```
$this->call('GET', route($route));
```

or

```
$this->visit(route($route))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem properly exists in code you haven't posted here. The problem is that the error handled in the code and converted to an error page. That is fine when visiting the page in the browser, but not so fine when debugging your tests. You can work your way around this by disabling the exception handler.

In your main testcase.php file add this function:

```
protected function disableExceptionHandling()
{
    $this->oldExceptionHandler = $this->app->make(ExceptionHandler::class);
    $this->app->instance(ExceptionHandler::class, new class extends Handler {
        public function __construct() {}
        public function report(\Exception $e) {}
        public function render($request, \Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
    });
}
```

Then in the tests that are failing you add this line at the top of your test:

```
$this->disableExceptionHandling();
```

You still will have the error, but it will be much more clear.

Comment: Thanks for that tip! Very useful! I'm Using MYSQL on my local machine and there was a PostgreSQL DB on Travis. Therefore a SQL Query could not be executed  like i was expecting (JSON-Field), cheers Stan